# React Router not rendering component on return

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

Handle delete works but does not render the component at `'/'`  after the item is deleted. Typing in that url will direct to the correct component.

I also want the `handleEdit` to also be referred by its link (/Job/Edit#, where # is rowData.id) instead of being directly called.

```
import {Link} from 'react-router-dom';
export default function ListJobs(props) {

  const url = 'http://localhost:8000/api/Jobs/'
  const [data, loading] = DataLoader(url);
  const handleEdit = (e,rowData) => {
    return <EditJob id={rowData.id} />
  }
  const handleDelete = (e,rowData) => {
    //edit operation
    DataDelete(url, rowData.id)
    return <Link to='/' />

  }
  const createButton = 
    <div style={{display: 'flex',  justifyContent:'center', alignItems:'center'}}>
    <Button 
        component={Link} to='/Job/Create'
        variant="contained"
        color="primary">
        Create New Job
      </Button>
    </div>

  return (
    <> {loading ? (
    <Grid
        container
        spacing={0}
        alignItems="center"
        justify="center"
        style={{ minHeight: '90vh' }}
      >
    <CircularProgress size="10vh" />
    </Grid>
    ) : (
      <MuiTable 
        model="Job" 
        data={data} 
        url={url} 
        handleEdit={handleEdit} 
        handleDelete={handleDelete} 
        createButton={createButton}
        />
    )}
    </>
    );
}
```

DataDelete:

```
export function DataDelete(url, id) { 
    url = url + id + '/'
    async function DeleteData() {
        const options ={
            method : 'DELETE',
            headers: {
                'Accept': 'application/json',
                'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=UTF-8'
            }
        }
        const response = await fetch(url, options)
            .then(response =>{
                console.log(response.status);
            });

        }       
    if (id === undefined)
        alert('Job not found.')
    else
        DeleteData()
    alert('Job Deleted!')
```

Answer (score 0):

Returning `Link` under no circumstances will trigger navigation. Technically you can return [Redirect](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Redirect), but with your structure it wouldn't help because the returned element isn't being rendered. Try instead using [history](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Hooks/usehistory) to navigate by pushing the route `"/"` to history:

```
import { useHistory } from "react-router-dom";

export default function ListJobs(props) {
  let history = useHistory();

  // ...

  const handleDelete = (e,rowData) => {
    //edit operation
    DataDelete(url, rowData.id)
    history.push("/");
  }

  // ...
}
```

Otherwise if you restructure component to conditionally render `<Redirect to="/" >` based on new state property that is set after delete is successful.

Comment: This works when I want to redirect to another page. What if I want the current page to re-render so the deleted item goes away?

Comment: Can you clarify why you need it to re-render? Aren't you removing the item from state when the delete is successful? That updated state should then be reflected in the consumer of that state that would get re-rendered as it receives new props. Either way I'm not sure what you are trying to achieve in handleDelete and handleEdit because are returning values from event handlers which would really never return values. You can technically use history to navigate to any path you need.

Comment: I added the code for DataDelete. I am deleting an item from my API. Items are stored as JSON. DataDelete removes the item from the API but it is still shown on the React page until i reload it.

Comment: I'd argue the whole point of an SPA is to avoiding refreshing the page to update what's rendered. Have you considered instead updating `data` when you add/remove/delete items? This could be easily done with `useState` and `useEffect`. `useEffect` to set data initially then `useState` to update `data` when these operations occur. With state being updated it will automatically re-render avoiding any need to refresh the page.

Comment: Would I use setState and useEffect in DataDelete or in the main file?

Comment: I'd say in the main file, but you can abstract them to custom hooks if you wanted.